# webcam on py2exe doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, windows, pygame, webcam, py2exe

Hi I write a program for using webcam but when I make it **exe** by py2exe
it crash because of this error.

[error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLLXb.jpg)

and this is my code

```
import pygame.camera
import pygame.image
import sys
pygame.camera.init()
cameras = pygame.camera.list_cameras()


webcam = pygame.camera.Camera(cameras[0])

webcam.start()

 # grab first frame
img = webcam.get_image()

WIDTH = img.get_width()
HEIGHT = img.get_height()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WIDTH, HEIGHT ) )
pygame.display.set_caption("pyGame Camera View")

while True :
    for e in pygame.event.get() :
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT :
            sys.exit()

     # draw frame
    screen.blit(img, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()
     # grab next frame    
    img = webcam.get_image()
```

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will work (I can't get the python code to run on my computer), but have you tried pyinstaller instead of Py2Exe (http://pyinstaller.org)?

Comment: I test this but it has the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally can make an executable file with cx_freeze
that can work with the camera, and the solution is that you should copy vidcapture.pyd into your file that have your program